# Bitrix24 CRM fields and sections

Tags: bitrix

We have renamed section in Bitrix as below.
Deals -> Projects, Companies -> Deals, Contacts -> Companies, Leads -> Contacts, However, while we open any of above, still require some renaming.

[image]

1. Top of the page it shows Company where it should be Deals
2. Products comes with empty.

Please advice.
Thanks

Comment: It will be very helpful if you make https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your host name / bitrix/admin/fileman_file_edit.php?lang=en&site=s1&path=%2Fbitrix%2Fcomponents%2Fbitrix%2Fcrm.company.show%2Ftemplates%2F.default%2Flang%2Fen%2Ftemplate.php&full_src=Y 
 you can changes in this file for your tab label name and save it. I am find out it from search option.

Answer (score 0):

You should not rename interface in such way because it confuses users!
It's not just names, they imply a lot of business logic.

Try to explain the reasons why you want to do this (what kind of business problem you are solving) and I will try to help to implement them in the right way.

But if you really want to rename items try to use localization module to translate interface strings (copy En locale and change some strings as you want).

I think it is the best option in your case.

You can find L10n module in admin interface: 
[image]

Comment: We have Business format of Companies->Deals->Projects->Products while in Bitrix it is Leads>Contacts>Companies->Deals->Products...That is why we need to configure it in our business line...

Comment: Renaming does not help you, because it is not change business logic of Bitrix. You need to change business logic of Bitrix, not the interface.

Please contact Bitrix support https://www.bitrix24.com/support/forum/ and explain them your  problem in more detailed way.

Comment: We have explained them and they keep suggesting paid support, while we have developers team can work on that. However, renaming seems the best option will provide us what we need at the end..

Comment: Ok then. To rename all items you should rename them in language files. You can find them in components templates folders, in folders named as language (en for English etc).

Comment: Hi, if you can share exact path (Procedure) or list of components to be changed in order to complete above task. We are not able to find appropriate folders. Thanks

Comment: Please see my answer above - I've added info how to change interface strings using Localisation module. If you would try to change  l10n manually in core lang files they will be deleted during next Bitrix update. So I recommend you to create *new* locale based on your current EN locale - see screenshot above. It saves your changes during next update.